# Custom sort with large number of items

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, custom-lists

I have data in a dynamic range which I want to sort horizontally by the values in the 1st row. A macro fills a range, e.g. ("a2 to f12") with names in row 2 and data below, and then it pastes names from another sheet in row 1. The names in row 1 also appear in row 2 but in a different order.

[image]

Then I want to sort the data in the range by the names in row 1 as below:

[image]

The code I use is:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ActiveSheet   'Sheet name: Data
Dim bottom As Long, right As Long
With sht
    bottom = .Cells(2, 2).End(xlDown).Row
    right = .Cells(2, 2).End(xlToRight).Column
End With

Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=Sheets("Data").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, right)), ByRow:=False

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(bottom, right)).Sort Key1:=Range(Cells(2, 1), _ Cells(2, right)), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=Application.CustomListCount + 1, _ MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlLeftToRight, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

Application.DeleteCustomList Application.CustomListCount
```

While the code usually works, sometimes it doesn't because the number of items can be several hundreds and it exceeds the limit of the custom list so, part of the data remains unsorted.
Also, after I delete the custom list, Excel crashes.
Is there any other way to sort my data without using a custom list?

Comment: One suggestion would be to make two copies of the first row in ArrayLists. Sort the one of the ArrayLists. For Each over the sorted arraylist and use the  IndexOf Method of the ArrayList to get the index of the sorted item in the original order  arraylist(then add 1 because arraylists use zero based indexes). You now know the column to move so its a case of some cutting and pasting in excel.

Comment: if you don't mind using a column helper, then copy the data to another column. Loop to the first row (to get each header name in each cell), then get the nth column where the looped cell value is found in the helper column. Something like this : `Set rgData = Range("A2", Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))` ... `Set rgTmp = Range("ZZ1").Resize(rgData.Rows.Count, rgData.Columns.Count)` ... `rgTmp.Value = rgData.Value` ... `For Each cell In Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlToRight))` ... `c = rgTmp.Rows(1).Find(cell.Value, lookat:=xlWhole).Column - rgTmp(1, 1).Column + 1` ... continue

Comment: `rgTmp.Columns(c).Copy Destination:=cell.Offset(1, 0)` .... `Next cell` ... `rgTmp.Clear`. Another way is without helper column, by putting the data in array. Something like this : `arrData = Range("A3", Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value` ... `Set rgHdr = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlToRight))` ... `For Each cell In rgHdr` ... `c = rgHdr.Offset(1, 0).Find(cell.Value, lookat:=xlWhole).Column` ... `cell.Offset(2, 0).Resize(UBound(arrData), 1).Value = Application.Index(arrData, 0, c)
` ... `Next` ... `rgHdr.Offset(1, 0).Value = rgHdr.Value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Custom-Sort Rows

- Qualify your worksheets and ranges: if you know the worksheet name, you don't want to use `ActiveSheet`; these cells `Cells(bottom, right)` are located in a worksheet, so qualify them.
- [`Right`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/right-function) is a VBA function. Surely you can make up your own variable name, e.g. `rCol`, `cRight`...
- Once you have added a custom list, its count has increased by 1, so the index `Application.CustomListCount + 1` shouldn't exist.
- Related to the `ByRow` argument, the [`documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.addcustomlist) states:
  *"If this argument is omitted and there are more columns than rows in the range, Excel creates a custom list from each row in the range."* This is true in our case: there are 6 columns and 1 row so *"each row"* is our only row hence one custom list will be added.

```vb
Sub SortColumns()
    
    Dim iclCount As Long: iclCount = Application.CustomListCount ' initial
    
    On Error GoTo ClearError ' start error-handling routine
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Data")
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    Application.AddCustomList rg.Rows(1)
    
    With rg.Resize(rg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1) ' exclude first row
        .Sort .Rows(1), xlAscending, , , , , , xlNo, iclCount + 1, , xlSortRows
    End With
    
ProcExit: ' Exit Routine
    On Error Resume Next ' prevent endless loop if error in the following lines
        With Application
            ' Delete all newly added custom lists (it's only one in this case).
            Do While .CustomListCount > iclCount
                .DeleteCustomList .CustomListCount
            Loop
        End With
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Sub
ClearError: ' continue error-handling routine
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit ' redirect to exit routine
End Sub
```